# If Statements Overwriting Previous Setter

Tags: c#, for-loop, if-statement

This is probably something really simple but I've tried a few things and cant get my head around how to prevent overwriting of a value in a foreach -> if statement.

I have a file which consists of `Entries` which have individual `Entry` inside of it. I am trying to set a different value for each individual `Entry` but currently it is setting them correctly but overwrites on each iteration.

```
var inputdoc = _service.ConvertToDocument(input);
var journal = _service.ConvertFromDocument(inputdoc);

foreach (var i in inputdoc .Body)
{
            
        foreach (var doc in journal.Entries)
        {
            doc.Entity = entityCode;

            if (doc.Entity == 12345)
            {
                if (i.Number == "VALBEU1") { doc.BankAccount = "435345345"; }
                if (i.Number == "VALBGB1") { doc.BankAccount = "324234234"; }
                if (i.Number == "VALBHU1") { doc.BankAccount = "45342123123"; }
                if (i.Number == "VALBMX1") { doc.BankAccount = "45546231"; }
                if (i.Number == "VALBSE1") { doc.BankAccount = "2344353123"; }
                if (i.Number == "VALBUS1") { doc.BankAccount = "234435645"; }
                if (i.Number == "VALBNO1") { doc.BankAccount = "234233123"; }
            }
        }
  }
```

So the issue is the end result of the single `Entry` end up having the same BankAccount value when it should be different depending on the `i.Number`.. so how is it that i can make it so that when I go through my `Entries` and set my `Entry` value that `BankAccount` number remains the same and moves onto the next Entry..sets that value and so on..

Comment: Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Comment: Side note: I suggest using `Dictionary<string, string>` instead of bunch of `if (i.Number == ...)`

Comment: Debug and walk through your logic step-by-step. People are giving a lot of small pieces of advice which are good code-review but even the fundamentals of your loop iterations don't make sense. Re-analyze what problem you're trying to solve and walk through your code one line at a time

Comment: The problem may be the fact that you seem to have an unrelated outer `for` loop. Since `journal` is created outside of that loop, you're iterating over `journal.Entities` once for every entry in `inputdoc.Body`. That shouldn't matter if your code is idempotent, but if you have side effects of setting properties, it could screw things up.

Comment: Slight optimization (will not solve your issue): use an `if (..) {..}  else if (..)` chain instead of separate `if` statements. Or look into `switch (i.Number) { case "VALBEU1": ..` (or a dictionary, as mentioned before)

Comment: Yes I mean currently optimization isn't my worry because I know i can use dictionaries and switch statements but I'm just trying to get the correct output at the moment.. I debugged my code and went through step by step.. and it's as mentioned, for each entry it is currently setting the value I want but when it goes to the next entry it overwrites that value depending on the if statement

Comment: I would suggest following @McAden's advice: debug and follow through step by step. It's not clear why you have nested loops, whether there could be side effects setting doc.BankAccount, and so on. Using a dictionary as suggested by Dmitry and following other suggestions would make the code more debuggable. Rethinking the problem and rewriting the code is likely to help more than trying to wrestle the current code into some workable state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zip the two sequences to create pairs of input documents and journal entries. Also, you can create a dictionary to look up the account numbers by input codes.

```
var accountDict = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    ["VALBEU1"] = "435345345",
    ["VALBGB1"] = "324234234",
    ["VALBHU1"] = "45342123123",
    ...
};

var inputdoc = _service.ConvertToDocument(input);
var journal = _service.ConvertFromLedger(ledger);

// Create tuples of input docs and journal entries
var inputAndDocs = inputdoc.Body.Zip(journal.Entries, (input, doc) => (input, doc);

foreach (var pair in inputAndDocs)
{
    var doc = pair.doc;
    doc.Entity = entityCode;
    if (doc.Entity == 23380 &&
        accountDict.TryGetValue(pair.input.Number, out var account))
    {
        doc.BankAccount = account;
    }
}
```

This assumes that input documents and the journal entries must be matched pairwise by the given order.

You assign always the same `entityCode` and then test inside the loop whether it matches a constant number. Since `entityCode` never changes, you could do this test in advance and skip the whole procedure alltogether.

```
if (entityCode == 23380) {
    // TODO: initialize
    foreach (var pair in inputAndDocs)
    {
        var doc = pair.doc;
        doc.Entity = entityCode;
        if (accountDict.TryGetValue(pair.input.Number, out var account)) {
            doc.BankAccount = account;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Why did your approach not work? Let's make a simple example:

```
int[] aArray = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] bArray = { 10, 20, 30 };
foreach (int a in aArray) {
    foreach (int b in bArray) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{a}, {b}");
    }
}
```

prints

```
1, 10
1, 20
1, 30
2, 10
2, 20
2, 30
3, 10
3, 20
3, 30
```

Using a zipped sequence and a single foreach; however, yields

```
1, 10
2, 20
3, 30
```

Instead of zipping, you could also use a single for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(a.Length, b.Length); i++) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{aArray[i]}, {bArray[i]}");
}
```

Comment: This is great, so lets say we have different entity values i.e. `23381` which also have their own `accountDict` values.. can I continue to add to the same dictionary and just add more if statements where it says `if(doc.Entity == 23380 &.." ?

Comment: You can also base your dictionary on value pairs by using a tuple as key.  Something like `var accountDict = new Dictionary<((int, string), string>() {
[(23380 , "VALBEU1")] = "435345345",
[(23380 , "VALBGB1")] = "324234234",
...
[(23381 , "VALBEU1")] = "895345345",
[(23381 , "VALBGB1")] = "774234234",
};` and tretrieve with tuple as well `accountDict.TryGetValue((eCode, number), out var account)`